# Fixing conflicting gestures between libinput and libinput-gestures

Tags: kde, multi-touch, libinput, gestures

Not sure if this question has been asked before but any direction would be appreciated!

Release:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

DE: KDE

Display Manager: X11

I am currently running into gesture conflicts with libinput and libinput-gestures, that is to say, I have libinput-gestures running, but using some of the gestures has undesired effects that are present independent of whether libinput-gestures is running. (For example, a three finger swipe to the right with a window selected, or not selected, has the desired effect of switching screens to the right when libinput-gestures is running, but the undesired effect of resizing a window to be half of my window pane on the screen before the libinput-gesture to switch screens kicks in )
The question would be, how do I customize or disable some of these other, pre-existing libinput gestures so I can get it to play nice with libinput-gestures?

here is the output of `libinput-gestures -d`

```
Hash: 5ed4f9aa29fda776dbbb6c36c619eb8d
Gestures configured in ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf:
swipe right      3 _internal ws_up
swipe left       3 _internal ws_down
swipe up         4 xdotool key control+F8
swipe up         3 xdotool key control+F9
swipe down       3 xdotool key super+Page_Down
swipe left       2 xdotool key alt+Left
swipe right      2 xdotool key alt+Right
pinch out          xdotool key ctrl+plus
pinch in           xdotool key ctrl+minus
libinput-gestures: device /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:15.1-platform-i2c_designware.1-event-mouse(event13): MSFT0001:01 04F3:309E Touchpad
libinput-gestures is already running for ad, terminating ..
```

Output of `libinput-gestures-setup status`

```
libinput-gestures is installed.
libinput-gestures is set up as a desktop application.
libinput-gestures is currently running as a desktop application.
libinput-gestures is set to autostart as a desktop application.
libinput-gestures is using custom configuration file.
```

and finally, a bit of introspection into some libinput config that was preset on my device, output from the command `xinput list-props 11`

```
Device 'MSFT0001:01 04F3:309E Mouse':
        Device Enabled (156):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (158): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (290):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (291):       0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (294):        0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (295):   0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (296):   0, 0, 1
        libinput Button Scrolling Button (297): 3
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (298): 3
        libinput Accel Speed (299):     -0.600000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (300):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (301):        1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (302):   1, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (303):   1, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (304):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (305):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (275):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (276):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (277):        0, 0
        Device Node (278):      "/dev/input/event11"
        Device Product ID (279):        1267, 12446
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (292):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (293):       1
```

Again any help appreciated, and I will provide and update this question with any other details that may be required, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is an issue with KDE not supporting editing of its xinput gestures,  would love for someone to correct me if I am wrong.